# Como criar um link "voltar"

Tags: javascript, html

Tenho a página index que coleta algumas informações que ela envia pra ela mesma. Depois o usuário acessa uma página de detalhes, onde nessa página, criei um link chamado "voltar". Porém, ao voltar pra a página index, os formulários são todos perdidos. Gostaria de saber como criar um link que retoma os formulários anteriores, da mesma forma que o "voltar" dos navegadores.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tente um link desta forma

```
<a href="#" onclick="history.go(-1); return false;">Link</a>
```

Comment: É um bom quebra-galho, mas o ideal é o Nicolas armazenar os estados dos formulários sempre que mudar página, para não depender do comportamento do navegador.

Comment: Como seria isso, Bacco?